# Why is value written by one CPU not seen by the other?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, memory-barriers, smp

Sorry if this is very basic. This is a simplified version of what I'm doing. I'm writing a kernel module. When it's running there will be two threads one two different physical CPU. I'm using a global variable to do certain communication between these threads. The strange thing is that sometimes the write by one thread is just not seen by the other. What could be the reason?

I suspect it has to do with memory barrier and maybe cache synchronization, so I've tried using smp_wmb() after the write, but it does not seem to help. And as far as I know I can't explicitly control cache synchronization. So I'm kinda stuck.

Any ideas?

EDIT: make it clear that the description is a simplified version.

Comment: Could be a lot of things.  Since kernel module makes me assume C, did you declare the variable volatile?

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I tried that.

Comment: Follow the patterns that other kernel code uses. Also, unless you're doing something incredibly unusual, the write memory barrier should be before the write. What meaning does this value convey?

Comment: You can provide a code or code snippets if you want a concrete answer

Comment: If you've two physical CPUs implementing NUMA, that behaviour seems very plausible without proper handling, whether on other architectures that may not occur (also note that this is no excuse for not doing things the right way). Anyway, NUMA or not, you should [read this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/christoph/gelato/gelato2005-paper.pdf).

Comment: Can you use https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-wait-event-interruptible.html and wake_up instead ? it has all the locking built in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're doing it wrong. Proper synchronization between CPUs is quite complicated and very architecture specific matter. You should use some of existing kernel mechanisms for thread synchronization. Unless you have some specific performance needs, just use spinlocks. Then, if needed, you may read a little bit more about different synchronization mechanisms and find one that best suits your workload.

To answer your question more directly - there are at least two issues you may be facing here:
   1. Instruction reorder by compiler which is usually taken care of by compiler barriers (i.e. `barrier()`).
   2. Out-of-order execution by CPU and cache coherency which is usually taken care of by memory barriers.

Details are architecture and usecase specific but you didn't provide any code or architecture details that we could analyze. So you might be required to use at least any and all of `barrier()`, `smp_wmb()`, `smp_rmb()` and `smp_read_barrier_depends()`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are facing the problem because of the compiler optimization.

Have you tried using `volatile` ? I think `volatile` will work in your case.

the `volatile` keyword should be used where concurrent un-synchronized operations are performed on a variable from more than one source (process). If the variable is declared volatile, then all processes will always directly access the variable from its memory location, as opposed to copying the variable in the microprocessor's cache and accessing it from there.

Comment: The volatile qualifier generally does not impact whether a variable's value is in cache or in memory.  It generally only effects whether variable's value is temporarily held in a register.